# Can't hide ul after clicking li element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After clicking on input I open `<ul>` list, need to close it on clicking `<li>` or in another place of screen

Here My JS & HTML

```js
$(".drop-down-input").click(function() {
  $(".dropdown-list").show();
});

// get "li" value and set to input

$(function() {
  $(".dropdown-list li").on('click', function() {
    $idinput = $(".dropdown-list").siblings('input').attr('id');
    $idinput = '#' + $idinput;
    $($idinput).val($(this).html());
    $(".dropdown-list").hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="styled-input-container drop-down-input">
  <input id="simple_2" class="drop-down-select" placeholder="input text" type="text">
  <ul class="dropdown-list">
    <li>eeee</li>
    <li>xxxx</li>
    <li>xxxx</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

`$(".dropdown-list").hide();` - this is not working, I don't now why?

Comment: Why get the id of an object by using attr, only to get the object again with said id?  You already have the object!

Comment: @Pete I fixed the indentation, it's not inside.

Comment: There's no reason to get the ID of the sibling and then use `$($idinput)`. Just put the sibling in a variable and use `$input.val()`

Comment: $idinput = $(".dropdown-list").siblings('input');
    $idinput.val($(this).html()); - not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the click event to the input element instead of the entire div otherwise event bubbling may happen. Although make it simple actually there is no need to get the `id` and select element again by the `id` value.

```
$(function() {
  $(".drop-down-input input").click(function() {
    $(".dropdown-list").show();
  });
  $(".dropdown-list li").on('click', function() {
    // if there is multiple `.dropdown-list` then get based on 
    // this context , eg : $(this).parent()
    $(".dropdown-list") 
      .hide() // hide the element
      .siblings('input') // get the sibling
      .val($(this).html()); // set it's value
  });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".drop-down-input input").click(function() {
    $(".dropdown-list").show();
  });
  $(".dropdown-list li").on('click', function() {
    $(".dropdown-list")
      .hide()
      .siblings('input')
      .val($(this).html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="styled-input-container drop-down-input">
  <input id="simple_2" class="drop-down-select" placeholder="input text" type="text">
  <ul class="dropdown-list">
    <li>eeee</li>
    <li>xxxx</li>
    <li>xxxx</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

Or use [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) to prevent event bubbling up.

```
$(function() {
  $(".drop-down-input").click(function() {
    $(".dropdown-list").show();
  });
  $(".dropdown-list li").on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".dropdown-list")
      .hide()
      .siblings()
      .val($(this).html());
  });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".drop-down-input").click(function() {
    $(".dropdown-list").show();
  });
  $(".dropdown-list li").on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".dropdown-list")
      .hide()
      .siblings()
      .val($(this).html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="styled-input-container drop-down-input">
  <input id="simple_2" class="drop-down-select" placeholder="input text" type="text">
  <ul class="dropdown-list">
    <li>eeee</li>
    <li>xxxx</li>
    <li>xxxx</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, it works!! How to do this: click in another place of screen and this form will close?

Comment: @ЕгорКротенко : yup use blur event to hide

Comment: use it on body? click on bodu than blur my list?

Comment: @PranavCBalan C Balan Oh.. trying close this menu 2 hours, Can you help me close it?